# Java color undefined

Tags: java, colors

Im trying to make a sepia effect and I need to make some colors be reduced to a certain percent. My compiler errors are these:

```
Error: The constructor java.awt.Color(double, double, double) is undefined

Error: The constructor java.awt.Color(int, int, double) is undefined

Error: The constructor java.awt.Color(int, int, double) is undefined
```

**This is my code:**

```
public void sepiaTint()
  {
    Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels();
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelArray.length; i++)
    {
     Pixel pixelObj = pixelArray[i];
     int amountRed = pixelObj.getRed();
     int amountGreen = pixelObj.getGreen();
     int amountBlue = pixelObj.getBlue();

     if (amountRed < 60)
     {
       Color newColor = new Color(amountRed*0.9, amountGreen*0.9, amountBlue*0.9);
       pixelObj.setColor(newColor);
     }
     if (amountRed >= 60 && amountRed <190)
     {
       Color newColor = new Color(amountRed, amountGreen, amountBlue*0.8);
       pixelObj.setColor(newColor);
     }
     else
     {
       Color newColor = new Color(amountRed, amountGreen, amountBlue*0.9);
       pixelObj.setColor(newColor);
     }
    }
    this.repaint();
  }
```

Comment: Im thinking it might have to do with my new color declaration not being all integers.

Comment: Casting the values to `float` or `int` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pixel.getRed()` returns an integer, so the `Color(float, float, float)` is useless to you. What you want is the `Color(int, int, int)` constructor.

`0.9` is interpreted as a double, so you have to cast it to an int again after calculating your value.

```
Color newColor = new Color((int)(amountRed*0.9), (int)(amountGreen*0.9), (int)(amountBlue*0.9));
```

Comment: +1. This is actually the correct answer, since using the constructor taking floats as argument would lead to colors that are much bigger than 1.0, which is the upper limit of the float arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`Color()` cunstructor should be like this

```
 new Color(amountRed*0.9F, amountGreen*0.9F, amountBlue*0.9F)
```

or

```
new Color((int)(amountRed*0.9), (int)(amountGreen*0.9), (int)(amountBlue*0.9))
new Color(amountRed, amountGreen, (int)amountBlue*0.8)
```

`0.9` is treated as `double` . `Color`  dont have any cunstructor which is having `double` perameters. So `0.9` should be converted to `float` like `0.9F`

Comment: The OP gets the color value as an integer between 0 and 255 from `Pixel.getRed()`. The `Color(float, float, float)` constructor expexts a value between 0.0 and 1.0. This just doesn't work.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider ok... Changing the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
Color newColor = new Color(amountRed*0.9F, amountGreen*0.9F, amountBlue*0.9F);
```